# Should their be a domain layer in a Java client app that uses an API to retrieve its data?

Tags: software, data

I'm somewhat new to Java, as I've only been coding in it for almost two years, so every couple months I try to grasp onto a new concept to improve my understanding and coding practices.

This is just a question to provide clarification, and get the opinions/best practices from engineers on software architecture.

Say I'm making a web app with Java (Spring, in this case). I have my views/HTML, and there is a form on one of my views that calls an endpoint in the client app, which is managed by a controller. There may be a service layer in my client app that handles any business logic.

The data that the app uses comes from another service; a REST API. This REST API has it's own set of controllers, a service layer that handles business logic, and a domain layer that talks to an ORM and handles the data.

My question is, should my client app have a domain layer that calls the REST API, or is it best practice to just call the service directly from my controller? I'd imagine that it might be redundant to use my controller to go into a domain manager to then call another endpoint in another app, but then I see the benefit of keeping things separate and neat.

Any opinions on this? Am I off in terms of anything? Do you think client apps should have a domain layer to then call another endpoint in another service, or should that endpoint just be called in the controller?

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with engineering, and seems far more appropriate for [SoftwareEngineering.SE] (though it might get closed there as opinion-based). I have removed the structures and architecture tags from the question.